# Are there examples of a core data persistent store for a fixed format?

Tags: macos, core-data

I've read blog posts about using a Core Data incremental store to implement an object access to/from an Internet database. I've read that CD stores can also be implemented for a classic file formats (instead of the Apple flavored XML, Binary, or SQLite files). Are there any examples of the latter?

(I've been thinking of an atomic store for a file type A, which is usually a few KB, and an incremental store for file type B, which is a list of type A, but can be GB in size. I would need to read type A from either a file directly or as an element of type B.)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking here. Core Data documents will always be XML, Binary, or SQLite at there core (your app can use any extension you want). XML and Binary are both read in completely when loaded whereas SQLite only loads the needed bits. There is an option to store an attribute of an entity in an external file if that's what you mean. For that take a look at the "Store in External Record File" option in the Core Data attribute inspector and google for "Core Data blobs" (start with anything written by Marcus Zarra)

Comment: AFAIK, it's **not** always; either the persistent-store and/or its coordinator class (not sure which) can be overridden to support non-Apple serialization formats. The various code samples that download records from the Internet are examples of this. I'm looking for machine-local examples.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to supply your own on disk setup but I don't think anyone has actually done it. it's gonna take lots of reading in the docs and experimenting I'm guessing.The persistent store is the one you would be customizing, likely through subclassing.